# How can I plot figures from pandas series in different windows?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new in python and I create pandas series in a for-loop. Each time I want to plot the series in a figure. I use `ax = series.plot(title = str(i)+'.jpg')` but all figures are plotted in same window. How can I plot them in different windows?

Comment: If you are looking for subplots then perhaps check this out: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/plot-multiple-plots-in-matplotlib/#:~:text=In%20Matplotlib%2C%20we%20can%20draw,appear%20on%20the%20same%20plot.

If you are looking to have them plotted in completely new windows/images then you need to define a new plot, you should look up matplotlib or pandas plotting documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using matplotlib, use

```
plt.figure()
```

for every new figure you want to plot.

You then show all figures with

```
plt.show()
```

also, you should check out what [subplots](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) does.